# How does resizing images taken by a binocular cameras affects the intrinsic camera matrix and extrinic camera matirx?

Tags: image, computer-vision, camera

I took a pair of images with a binocular camera.The intrinsic and extrinsic matrix are known.
Now the images are resized to 0.5 times.
How to change the intrinsic matrix and extrinic matrix to maintain the 3D point cloud unchanged?

I tried to directly magnify the point cloud to twice, but it seems inaccurate

Answer (score 0):

The camera matrix changes from `K = [[fx, s, cx], [0, fy, cy], [0, 0, 1]]` to `K' = [[fx/2, s, cx/2], [0, fy/2, cy/2], [0, 0, 1]]`. The nonlinear distortion parameters are unaffected by resizing (assuming you are using the OpenCV Brown-Conrady model) because they are defined with respect to normalized image coordinates. The extrinsic parameterse are unaffected.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a new question now: how the distortion matrix changes?

Comment: Re-read my answer, I specifically mention the distortion parameters.